# Having problems reading data from a file - java

Tags: java, file-io, delimiter

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with delimiters and I'm relatively new with Java and can't seem to find an answer. I have to read from a file called Simulation.Configuration which has this data in it:

```
    dimensionX: 100
    dimensionY: 100
    numberOfMobileObjects: 5
    durationOfSimulationTime: 10
    WarningGeotask: 1, 3
    WarningGeotask: 2, 3
    CounterGeotask: 1, 3
    PopuplationMonitoringGeotask: 2, 3, 3
```

I have a scanner reading through to find the data and do certain things with them. I can easily get past the labels (dimensionX, dimensionY, and so forth)but can't seem to get to the numbers. I've tried a lot of ways using delimiters to reach those numbers, but cannot seem to get to them.The most recent one I've tried is using

```
scanner.useDelimiter("[ ,:]");
```

to get through to the data. When I do this, it gives me an InputMismatchException. 
Here's how I am reading the file:

```
    Scanner scanConfig = new Scanner(new File("Simulation.Configuration"));

    scanConfig.useDelimiter("[ ,:]");

    int dimensionX = 0;
    int dimensionY = 0;
    int numberOfMobileObjects = 0;


    while(scanConfig.hasNextLine()){

        String nextLabel = scanConfig.next();
        if(nextLabel.equals("dimensionX")){

            dimensionX = scanConfig.nextInt();
        }
        if(nextLabel.equals("dimensionY")){

            dimensionY = scanConfig.nextInt();
        }
        if(nextLabel.equals("numberOfMobileObjects")){

            numberOfMobileObjects = scanConfig.nextInt();
        }
```

I've looked all over and couldn't find anything that helped my situation. Any tips on this would be lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) you've provided for the delimiter isn't doing what you think it is. I would take
this approach instead.

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String[] array = input.split(":");
String label = array[0];
String data = array[1];    
String[] number = data.split(",");   
Integer x = new Integer(number[0]);
```

[Documentation for String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Your useDelimiter argument is wrong. "[ ,:]" uses exactly one character as a delimiter. You want any set of those. Simply change it to:  "[ ,:]+".

Comment: that will still throw the exception